# open("text.txt","w+") does not create a new file

Tags: python, file-io, filenotfoundexception, file-not-found

I am trying to create a text file, using open(filename,'x'). I have tried x = 'a+', 'w+', 'w'. I am using windows 10, vs code "run python file in terminal", and python 3.8.2

```
    import os

    print("cwd",os.getcwd())

    scriptpath = os.path.dirname(__file__)

    filename = "test.txt" #1
    #filename = scriptpath + "/test.txt" #2
    #filename = r"C:\Users\harki\Documents\ALGO\ALGO-NPL\test.txt" #3

    f = open(filename,'w+')
    f.write("test")
    f.close()
```

running with first filename:

```
PS C:\Users\harki\Documents\ALGO\ALGO-NPL> & C:/Users/harki/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/python.exe c:/Users/harki/Documents/ALGO/ALGO-NPL/test_save.py
cwd C:\Users\harki\Documents\ALGO\ALGO-NPL
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/harki/Documents/ALGO/ALGO-NPL/test_save.py", line 11, in <module>
    f = open(filename,'w+')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'test.txt'
```

running with second filename:

```
PS C:\Users\harki\Documents\ALGO\ALGO-NPL> & C:/Users/harki/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/python.exe c:/Users/harki/Documents/ALGO/ALGO-NPL/test_save.py
cwd C:\Users\harki\Documents\ALGO\ALGO-NPL
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/harki/Documents/ALGO/ALGO-NPL/test_save.py", line 11, in <module>
    f = open(filename,'w+')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c:/Users/harki/Documents/ALGO/ALGO-NPL/test.txt'
```

running with third filename:

```
PS C:\Users\harki\Documents\ALGO\ALGO-NPL> & C:/Users/harki/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/python.exe c:/Users/harki/Documents/ALGO/ALGO-NPL/test_save.py
cwd C:\Users\harki\Documents\ALGO\ALGO-NPL
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/harki/Documents/ALGO/ALGO-NPL/test_save.py", line 11, in <module>
    f = open(filename,'w+')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\harki\\Documents\\ALGO\\ALGO-NPL\\test.txt'
```

**Edit:**
Moving project outside of "Documents" folder solved the problem

Comment: Not related to the problem, I'm just curious: I always see people here using the `w+` instead of `w`, even though they're only writing, not reading. Why do you do that?

Comment: I ran your code and it worked fine for me.  Check for simple mistakes such as accidentally running a different version of Python or a problem with VSCode.  I've encountered a few problems with VSCode when using it to develop Python 3.x.x and C++.

Comment: I couldn't replicate the problem. Your code works fine. Maybe it's a permissions issue? Did you try running cmd/powershell in administrator mode "Run as administrator"?

Answer (score 0):

I used this code to define file path and it works for me:

```
filename = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), 'folder/name', 'test.txt')
```

And then I create the file by using joblib or pickle.

In your case, it is similar to the second filename, just need to add the `join()` function

Comment: Shouldn't it be `os.path.join()`?

Comment: Yes, I imported it with from os.path import join, dirname, realpath. So it should be os.path.join(dirname(realpath(__file__)), 'folder/name', 'test.txt')

Comment: You should make it explicit in the answer.

Comment: Done, I changed it.

Comment: `filename = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), 'test.txt')`  creates the same path and error as filename #3 above

Comment: Then I am not too sure about the problem, it should work fine.